# How to use transfer learning in machine learning for supervised classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest, transfer-learning

I am using the scikit-learn random forest and neural network classifier for a supervised classification. The code is pretty much the template code. Now, I need to use transfer learning to improve accuracy. My train and test files are similar csv files with a number of columns as features and one column as label. Can anyone provide an example in python?

Comment: As a note, I need to do some feature selection, or instead of using absolute values, use percentage of values.

Comment: I think your question is too broad. It would be good, if you could provide some info on where you want to transfer from. E.g. for neural nets it is quite common to use pre trained nets of similar problems and retrain them on the specific problem. But because you mention random forests, I guess you don't have a image classification problem but most likely tabular data. So you most likely won't find a pretrained net that can be refitted to your problem. But of course there are other ways to do transfer learning.

Comment: But to get a suggestion, more info is needed on what your problem is like.

Comment: Transfer learning in basic terms, using a pretrained model weights for your own model and dataset. So that way what you generally do is just get pre trained model architecture, and weights chop off the output layer and adjust in a way that fits your task. Train the model by initializing with pretrained weights on your training dataset. I think there might be a misunderstanding of "transfer learning" inferring from what you wrote.

Comment: @jottbe Yes, it is network data in a csv file in excel format, no image

Comment: @null, it could be, I am using excel data essentially so how do I apply transfer learning.